# Class property: "Object is possibly undefined" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This seems like a pretty straightforward typescript snippet:

```js
class Example {
    private items: Record<string, number[]> = {}

    example(key: string): void {
        if (this.items[key] === undefined) {
            this.items[key] = []
        }
        this.items[key].push(1)
    }
}
```

but it's giving the following error for `this.items[key].push(1)`:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

This works:

```
this.items[key]?.push(1)
```

but I'd like to understand why the compiler doesn't respect the explicit undefined check.

Comment: Maybe because it's a property access, not a variable

Comment: What version of Typescript? I'm not getting that error in 4.2.4

Comment: What happens if you replace your whole `if` with `this.items[key] ??= [];` ?

Comment: Odd, I'm also on 4.2.4.

Comment: @blex same error!

Comment: @Bergi I tried assigning `this.items[key]` to a variable, same result.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` option. [Repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0KATgJYBuYALpidUhAFzQBK6wA9kQCYA8ElpAHYBzADTRBAVyQAjdEQDaAXQB80ALzYAvjjwF0iVBgAUAa3QBPJvyHCAlEzLsSXbHoIESAM2jHKACxIIADpadHoFcwslDXVNSUEudC8SQXQuOzcPbIIAoNC6CEjLGM1ld2ydHPw8kLCIqKVglEkIf2MARjsKnS0gA). @user3717031 Please always share your *tsconfig* :)

Comment: @user3717031 By "using a variable", I meant [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0KATgJYBuYALpidUhAFzQBK6wA9kQCYA8ElpAHYBzADTRBAVyQAjdEQDaAXQB80ALzYAvjjwF0iVBgAUAa3QBPJvyHCAlEzLsSXbHoIEMlaGCJEN0JQAFiQQAHS06PQK5hZKANzuHtAkAGbQxr7+6jnQkoJc6Kkkguhcdm7JVT5+AcGhEXQQMZZKAcpJHjrVNURhKJIQQcYAjHZJOlpAA)

Comment: @Bergi thank you! You are correct, this is the culprit. I will be sure to include my tsconfig in any future questions :)

Comment: Turning off noUncheckedIndexedAccess will allow any un-declared field in the type - globally for all objects. You're better off just using any instead of globally disabling checking if a variable key is defined or not.  Just FYI if you loop / map your object it fill fail type check because indexes are expected to be strings - Record<[key: string], number[]>. How you're setting it it to string  is not the same as the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript is showing this error because you are not correctly checking if your variable is undefined.  It appears that you're defining it before reaching the block but it could potentially not be defined.

This is why you should not disable `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` - in this case - it would introduce a place for a bug.

FYI - adding ? at the end of the key is telling ts that you know for a fact that the key is defined - don't check. It should be avoided if possible.

Not checking - you original check

```
    example(key: string): void {
        // this is checking before your push
        if (this.items[key] === undefined) {
            this.items[key] = []
        }
        // independent from previous check and still reachable even if the variable is undefined
        this.items[key].push(1)
    }
```

Checking

```
    example(key: string): void {
        const item = this.items[key];
        if (!item) {
            this.items[key] = [1]
        } else {
            item.push(1)
        }
    }
```

A side note when checking if a key exist a more reliable approach over just just check if it's undefined would be `this.items.hasOwnProperty(key)` or `!(key in this.itmes)` because a value could be undefined, which if checking for undefined would have an opposite result as you were expecting.

This doesn't apply to the example above because it's cast to a variable prior to checks so it can only be a string or undefined - it can't contain a value of undefined

Comment: I'm a fan of `(this.items[key] = this.items[key] ?? []).push(1)` though it's kind of abusing the assignment expression

Comment: As long as it's readable and understandable by a future maintainer or your future self - it's good in my book.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer! I'm still not sure how `this.items[key]` could be undefined in the first example. JavaScript is single threaded, so there's no way that the value of `this.items[key]` can change between those statements.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with the examples provided: [repro](shorturl.at/opxCU)

Comment: I updated the answer - I forgot to assign the dynamic object key to a const.